# How to restore previous 'set -x' option in bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to debug my scripts. For example a.sh call b.sh.

```
#a.sh
echo "in a.sh"
source b.sh

#b.sh
echo "in b.sh"
```

If I'm sure b.sh is OK and just want to debug a.sh, I run as

```
bash -x a.sh
```

How to disable the display '-x' setting in b.sh, maybe modify b.sh as

```
#b.sh
x_option=$(get -x) # if there is such function
set +x
echo "in b.sh"
[ $x_optoin = 1 ] && set -x
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to provide the answer.  If you don't like any of the provided answers, answering your own question is fine (and you can accept it, too, only you have to wait a while).

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/648331/how-to-properly-restore-settings-when-running-a-script-using-source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the bash [reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> The current set of options may be found in $-.

Which means you can look in that value for the current state of `-x`.